# Dynamic jQuery noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm currently developing a central css and js toolbox which will be used in different webapps, e.g. a typo3 website, a rails app and a magento store.

My problem is that magento uses protoype.js and jQuery needs to run in noConflict mode.

Is there a way to use jQuery in noConflict mode in the magento shop anhin normal mode for the other two?

Btw: the toolbox compiles the js with gulp. Maybe someone ran accross a solution to compile a normal mode js file and one with no conflict where $ will be replaced by $j.

Hope somebody can help me out! Thank you!

Comment: Use `jQuery`, not `$`, and your problems are solved.

Comment: So damn right! Thank you sir!

Comment: You can also work in a closure : `(function($){})(jQuery)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to solve your problem.

1) Use jQuery rather than $, as Meagar said.

2) You can use following syntax -

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And Use **$j** object for your jQuery script.

**$j** is just for example. You can use another word as well.

For more info - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/